# Could not retrieve a valid Token response from Token URL + Twitter API

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am doing the login using twitter in my zend framework application. But after authenticating from twitter it showing the following error :

```
Message:Could not retrieve a valid Token response from Token URL: /oauth/access_token?oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_nonce=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1352270857&oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_version=1.0
&oauth_verifier=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&oauth_signature=wv5gdop77NA9BeZI7ilQcEFsqGH8CeR4%3D Invalid / expired Token
```

Following is my code :

```
    public function twittercallbackAction() {
            $path = realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/');
            set_include_path($path);
            $config = array(
                "callbackUrl" => "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/register/twittercallback",
                "siteUrl" => "http://twitter.com/oauth",
                "consumerKey" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "consumerSecret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            );

            $consumer = new Zend_Oauth_Consumer($config);
            if (!empty($_GET) && isset($_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN'])) {            
                $token = $consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, unserialize($_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN']));
                // Now that we have an Access Token, we can discard the Request Token
                // get users timeline            
                // $_SESSION['TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN'] = null;
            } else {
                // Mistaken request? Some malfeasant trying something?
                exit('Invalid callback request. Oops. Sorry.');
            }
}
```

I am searching this issue on google but not getting any solution.

How can I deal with this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved it myself....  :-)

The problem was twitter updated their api url:

From

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?
```

To

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?
```

and it gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks for poiting me to the right direction. I had similar problem. The thing I had changed was the `siteUrl` parameter in `Zend_Oauth_Consumer` config. Right one is `'siteUrl' => 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth'`.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code, which I assume you got from http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.oauth.introduction.html, and it works properly. Here are a few things to check:

- Is your consumer app key/secret valid?
- Does your server have the correct date/time set?
- What's your code for generating your request token?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally I solved it. Problem was not in posted code. It was the issue of API url. See my answer.